# SQL - Join two query in same query with two rows

Tags: sql

i have one query that i need include the status in another row, i think that it's easy but i'm not remember it..

```
status
A
B
C
D
job
1
2
3
```

i want a output like:

```
job   status
1       A
1       B
1       C
1       D
2       A
2       B
2       C
2       D
...
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: You are getting downvotes because your question is very very poor. You did not give us **anything** to work with. We do not know the table structure. We do not know the field names. We do not know the relationships. We do not even know what RDBMS (database software) you are using. Also, this is a question that is asked and answered at least once every week so there is **a lot** of answers out there. Finally, you did not provide us with what you have tried.

Answer (score 3):

that is called `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT *
FROM status CROSS JOIN job;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing your table layout here **because you did not give it in your question**.

```
SELECT t1.job, t2.status
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.something = t2.something
```

Note that **if you had given the table structure** `something`, `t1` and `t2` would actually be the real names.

If there is no particular key and you just want to match every value of t1.job to every value of t2.status then this will do the job:

```
SELECT t1.job, t2.status
FROM t1, t2
```

Comment: 1. i did not downvote 2. the answer isnt specific,what made you think theres must be inner join ? `INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.something = t2.something`

Comment: Well that's why I provided both possible cases because OP failed to ask a proper question and it's not clear from his question.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read a little bit about JOINs in SQL, here's a good resource:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

As per your case, you can simply do:

```
SELECT * FROM job, status
```

Assuming that those are table names and these are the only columns in there.

EDIT:
Link with explanation on how CROSS JOIN works as well:
http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php